# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Isolated Shell project template missing?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017, vsx

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Isolated Shell project template missing ?Any clue if i missed any extension pack pack or individual workload while installing ?

Comment: You'll only get that template when you have the VS 2017 SDK installed.  I don't see it available on MSDN yet.  Give it time.

Comment: I thought since roslyn MS started disintegrated VS SDK in several nuget packages , So it should come eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this writing (April 10, 2017) the Visual Studio 2017 Isolated / Integrated Shells haven't been announced yet. It seems that Microsoft will provide them but they need time to accommodate to the new Visual Studio 2017 internal component structure and setup. As you may know, Visual Studio 2017 doesn't use GAC or normal Windows Registry (it uses a private Registry hive) and its setup is based on workloads and very granular individual components. For example, the standalone Visual Studio 2017 Team Explorer was announced last week, weeks after the initial launch of Visual Studio 2017 RTM. With the Shells the same will happen eventually.

Answer (score 1):

And now 3 years later (March 2020), it looks like Microsoft gave up on the Isolated Shell for Visual Studio. I could not find an official retirement of the software, however 2015 is the latest version I have found any reference to.

- http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/04/11/microsoft-the-visual-studio-shells-and-the-old-versions/
- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/
- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/